# What are some good resource for learning how car key and wireless door lock systems work?

Tags: automotive, rfid, security

I understand that most car keys include a 434MHz transmitter, as well as 125KHz RFID transponder. The 434MHz transmitter is used for operating the door locks, and the 125KHz RFID transponder is the vehicle immobilizer.

How do I find out how the program running on the microcontroller for the 434MHz transmitter is structured?

Comment: KeeLoq is probably one good thing to search on.

Comment: PeterJ: Any idea what has replaced KeyLoq, now that it has been broken?

Comment: No I'm not really up with it, although probably nothing because it sounds the side-channel attack needs physical access to the receiver followed by 100 days of processing on a fast dedicated machine. Probably not the easiest way to steal a car!

Comment: From what I understand, the 36-bit manufacturer codes for most make+model are known, and it's only the the last 28 bits of the 64-bit KeeLoq key that need to be brute forced. This used to take 10 hours in 2008, but now only takes a few minutes (thanks to CUDA/OpenCL).